# WSO2 CEP failover and active-active mode

Tags: wso2, high-availability, failover, complex-event-processing

I use CEP in version 3.1.0, and I made two instances on two servers in HA failover mode. In documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Complex+Event+Processor) failover mode and active-active mode are set up the same. I have a little problem with it, becasue once I run this instances and they download messages from message broker, they work in failover mode and all messages are downloaded by one CEP (second CEP are waiting). When I run this instances second time, both download messages. I guess that, active-active mode turns up.

Is there any property in xml files, that I can change to get only failover mode all the time? Or maybe I miss something in this documentation?

Comment: Ticket for it => https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-995

Comment: Above ticket has been fixed in CEP 4.0.0 (Beta release is available). You can build pack from github repository => https://github.com/wso2/product-cep